# Java timer that prevents shutdown if and only if tasks are queued

Tags: java, timer

I have a `java.util.Timer` that I use for throttling email sends (if a status email has been sent too recently, then don't send one now but instead create a timer task to send it later with any new statuses).

What I would like is to ensure any queued email is eventually sent, but that if none are queued then the program can shut down normally.  Unfortunately I'm unable to decide how to go about it:

- If I leave the Timer in default (non-daemon) mode, then it will keep the process from exiting until it's explicitly cancelled.
- If I set the Timer to daemon mode, then it will allow shutdown, but any queued tasks (i.e. unsent emails) will be abandoned.

What I've done so far is to explicitly cancel the Timer (and let it be garbage collected) after the email is sent, and then recreate a new Timer when needed for future delayed emails.  This seems like needless churn.

Is there a way to control the Timer's daemon state?  Or an alternative to Timers that would achieve this delayed email scheme?

**Edit** Note that my current solution, however icky, has the advantage that email sends are "fire and forget".  Once the call to the email sender has been made, the Timer's non-daemon state ensures that the email will be sent even some other part of the application causes a shut down in the mean time.  This avoids the need for special application shutdown code to control the Timer.

Comment: I don't know how your status emails work, but what triggers them? Can you just a status email that sends one out periodically (see @tieTYT's answer)? Or it a user driven event?

Comment: The emails are sent when something goes wrong; the first time something goes wrong it needs to be sent immediately.  But if multiple other things go wrong afterwards it's less urgent and they should be batched.

Answer (score 1):

If the thread pool executor suggested by @tieTYT doesn't work for your needs, why not just use a non-daemon timer shut down on the timer on application exit? Assuming you are shutting down cleanly, your code should provide a way to do some steps on cleanup. Alternatively as a last effort you could add a shutdown hook to cancel the timer.

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc of Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) says:

> Java 5.0 introduced the java.util.concurrent package and one of the concurrency utilities therein is the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate or delay. It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the Timer/TimerTask combination, as it allows multiple service threads, accepts various time units, and doesn't require subclassing TimerTask (just implement Runnable). Configuring ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with one thread makes it equivalent to Timer.

So maybe you should be using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor instead and then you can prevent shutdown by using [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

Comment: I don't think ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor actually helps -- I would still need to have some explicit shutdown code somewhere in the app to call `shutdown` on it (which I think is what you mean by using Thread.join?).

Comment: Yes that's what I mean by `Thread.join`.  It waits until that thread finishes.  I don't know how to do that on a Task, but it might be possible.

Comment: What you with ThreadPools is `awaitTermination()` instead of `Thread.join()`. @Edmund can you put some shutdown-code that would wait for all emails to be sent at the end of your main method or is that not possible?

Comment: @jboi - Shutdown code is something I've avoided so far; I think this problem would be a lot easier with it but the rest of the application is complex enough... so if I can continue to avoid it, I'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this so it might be a bit daft, but could you not set your timer to non-daemon and register a shutdown hook that would wait on the mail queue to be empty before cancelling the timer?

Answer (score 0):

I see three possible ways to handle that. Non of them looks trivial from your situation.

1. Put some shutdown code at the end of your application to wait till email is sent out. You can do this with plain threads, or - more elegant - with a Threadpool.
2. You configure the Thread as Deamon which effectively keeps the JVM running till the email is sent.
3. You delegate the work to another process like an ApplicationServer. This must be an administrated instance, ensured to be running. You can then send a bean to it, that waits and send the email.

Which one is your preferred way?